# Combine 2 observables and get output from one which complete first

Tags: android, rx-java

I have a subscription that wait for the push notification and another one that is polling the server to get response. I want to start both observable together and return the data from the one which finish first. What would be operator to use here?

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to have the data of the first one to finish, you have to put the data somewhere until you get to the terminal event by collecting each into its own list and using `amb` that picks the source that signals an event (the collected list) first. Then you can unroll the list back to individual items.

```
Observable<A> source1 = ...
Observable<A> source2 = ...

Observable.amb(source1.toList(), source2.toList())
.flatMapIterable(list -> list)
.subscribe(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

The operator you are looking for is [first](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/first.html). Of-course, you'll have to merge the Observables first (by using [merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html), or probably better - mergeDelayError, so if only one of them fails, you'll still get the first which finishes with a vaild result).

Should look like:

```
Observable.mergeDelayError(pushObservable, pullObservable)
        .first()
        .subscribe(data->...);
```